# Is it possible to have a network access after a "pause" event in PhoneGap iOs App?

Tags: javascript, ios, networking, cordova, websocket

My PhoneGap application need to emit a websocket (to update the connection status) message to the server when the "[pause](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#pause)" event is captured.

### Android

With Android device there is no problem by using this piece of code :

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
    document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
        socket.emit('changeStatus', 'incative');
    });
    document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
        socket.emit('changeStatus', 'active');
    });
}, false);
```

---

### iOs

In iOs this is a different kettle of fish. Indeed here is the official PhoneGap documentation about the "[pause](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#pause)" event :

**iOS Quirks**

**In the pause handler, any calls that go through Objective-C will not work, nor will any calls that are interactive, like alerts. This means that you cannot call console.log (and its variants), or any calls from Plugins or the PhoneGap API. These will only be processed when the app resumes (processed on the next run-loop).**

When they say "calls that go through Objective-C will not work", are they talking about using network access ?
Indeed when I test my app on iOs my "changeStatus" message with the value "inactive" is send when I resume my application.

Here is my second question : **Is it possible in phonegap iOs app to access the server after capture a "pause" event ?**

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's possible because of several security issues on iOS. 
As alternative solution, you can run an echo function at socket server end, which will continuously emit message to that particular user at a particular intervals. If user responds to that message, you can consider that user as a active user  else consider him as  inactive user.

It's also not a good practice for user to send his activity status. Consider what will happen if user lost his connectivity? You will never come to know if he is active orsleeping..
Hence its better to check it by ping at server end..